# How to split a string and extract its specific elements?

Tags: string, bash, shell, sh

I need split a string and extract specific elements.

For instance, I have `str`

```
str='C50F2N2Ne50A13.224343968R2'
```

And than, I need extract ...

```
C = 50
F = 2
N = 2
Ne = 50
A = 13.224343968
R = 2
```

Other example ...

```
str='C5F10N2Ne5A2.0330517838R2'
```

And than, I need extract

```
C = 5
F = 10
N = 2
Ne = 5
A = 2.0330517838
R = 2
```

My first idea was to extract uppercase characters ...

```
classes=$(tr -dc '[:upper:]' <<< $name)
```

But It return only `CFNNAR`.

My second idea was to split by specific character [delimiter]

```
classes=(${name//F/ })
classes=(${classes//C/ })
```

But I can not isolate the values.

I tried split by number of characters, but each part of string can vary its size.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides all the usual caveats about never using eval, try:

```
 eval  $( echo $str | sed 's/\([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\)/ \1=/g')
```

or, get all modern and use:

```
 echo $str | sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]+)/ \1=/g'
```

Comment: It return a array? I try `values=($(echo $name | sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]+)/ \1=/g'))`

Comment: A tiny modification of William's second version: `echo $str | sed -E 's/([0-9.]+)/ = \1\n/g'`